# htaccess multiple URL shortner

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a shortner for a profile page. I now want to add an additional shortner to a tag page.

CURRENT CODE (for profile - works fine):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cd/profile.php?username=$1
```

My problem is when I want to differiantiate the pattern to add the tag page:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^user/()$ dh/profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^tag/()$ cd/tags.php?tag_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now, neither works. I am testing it using XAMP and my domains at the moment would be:

1) Directory for profile --> localhost/cd/profile.php?username=John

2) Directory for tags    --> localhost/cd/tags.php?tag_name=blue

Do I have to restructure the root to each page? How can I make it work?

Cheers

Comment: missed the .* in both brackets in the second part of the code. Consider it as if it was there.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex are incorrect in both rules.

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ /dh/profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^tag/(.+)$ /cd/tags.php?tag_name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also remember that `RewriteCond` is only applicable to the very next `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I now tried and it redirects. The only problem is the CSS. It doesn't apply the CSS to the page. Do you know why?

Comment: You should use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: and why wouldn't that happen when using only the profile redirect? If just the profile, everything was smooth without having to declare the full path.

Comment: Because of the nature of relative URLs which changes with the current path. So relative path from `/` is not same as relative path from `/user/someone`

Comment: I am testing the profile page. I certaintly go to the page though I've already changed to complete URL to reference both the CSS files and JS and the page still has no CSS applied. Any ideas what I may be missing? I have for example: <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/dh/css/bootstrap.css"/> to reference the bootstrap css

Comment: That's not correct URL path. URL are supposed to start from `http://` so try: `httpd://localhost/css/bootstrap.css` for example.

Comment: not working. the path to the css files is: /dh/css/css files. I currently have href="/css/bootstrap.css" and even if I change it to your suggestion or my attempts, it doesn't resolve the css file :\ Iam out of ideas

Comment: Because your own path is still not correct. I shouldn't be telling you this since that is your own setup. If there is `/dh/` then correct path is `httpd://localhost/dh/css/bootstrap.css` whatever path you see you should be able to test/verify the same from a browser window.

Comment: I understand, and thanks for all your help up until now. I just tried as you suggested. For some reason none of the options makes it work :\

Comment: What happens when you enter : `http://localhost/dh/css/bootstrap.css` in the browser. I had `httpd://` instead of `http://`

Comment: Yes, I tried and now mos of the page is well displayed. I guess I still have to update other css and js links. The only drawback is it gets very very slow to load the page. Previously was instantaneous

Comment: It will be slow initially only. And remember rewrite rule cannot make it slow :)